# Will my app be rejected by Apple if I ask user for a 5 star and positive review comment after I will award them my In-App for free?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I have a simple app with a few paid In-App purchases.

Will I be rejected when I inform user about my latest promotion? User may get In-App for free only when give me positive review and 5 star in App Store. Once it will be done, user can ask me about free In-App.

Will it be in good with Apple Review Guidelines?

Comment: Whether aplle will allow it I would hope not. But u would check the law as this sounds like deceit forcing you users to lie.

Comment: Also you need to worry about government views https://www.gov.uk/cma-cases/online reviews eg they will be asking apple how these websites handle reviews about products or services that the reviewer has received a payment or other incentive to review.

Comment: I can say that as a user, I really dislike being hounded for reviews and ratings.  To be “bribed” is even worse because I wouldn’t be able to trust the reviews about the app. I would be questioning whether they were legit or not.   To me, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

See [Apple Review Guidelines - 3.2.2 Unacceptable](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#unacceptable):

> - (vi) Apps should allow a user to get what they’ve paid for without performing additional tasks, such as posting on social media, uploading contacts, checking in to the app a certain number of times, etc. **Apps should not require users to rate the app, review the app**, watch videos, download other apps, tap on advertisements, or take other similar actions in order to access functionality, content, use the app, or receive monetary or other compensation, including but not limited to gift cards and codes.
> - ...
> - (ix) Apps must not force users to **rate the app, review the app,** download other apps, or perform other similar actions in order to access functionality, content, or use of the app.

The behaviour described feels against the intent of the above guidelines, but only Apple's reviewers can authoritatively answer this question. [Contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) directly, they may be able to provide further clarity.

Comment: So it will be rejected, right?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk That's not what Graham Min said. Graham said your plan _feels_ like it violates Apple's intent, and suggests you contact Apple to ask. _Feels like_ is less certain than _will be rejected_.

Comment: Graham is very direct with his answer @BartłomiejSemańczyk -  *only Apple's reviewers can authoritatively answer this question*.  This is pretty clear.